# adb shell input touch tap works on one device but doesn't work on the other with exact same screen resolution

Tags: shell, touch, adb

I'm running this command against Asus Zenfone (4.4.2 android) with resolution 720x1280 to perform a button press:

`adb shell input touchscreen tap 104 1252`

however same command doest work for LG G4C (5.0.2 android version) with exact same screen resolution.

Screen density on both is 320.

The command that works on LG phone is:

`adb shell input touchscreen tap 63 1172`

I wonder why this is happening.. i was thinking the touch coordinate is only dependent on screen resolution. Does android version matter?

Comment: Enable `show pointer location` in `Developer settings` before you try command. Just wonder have you tried `adb shell input tap xx xx` ? without `touchscreen`.

Answer (score 0):

The touch screen is an input device. The display is an output device. These two are separate devices which may have completely different resolutions. It's up to the manufacturer of the specific device to properly configure it - so the coordinate translation would happen seamlessly. It depends on neither Android version nor screen resolution/density.

Anyway - do yourself a favor and do not use the hardcoded coordinates. Depending on the programming language you are using for your automation - just use one the multitude of frameworks/libraries which would allow you to tap a specified UI element on the screen.